# Replaced a dimmer switch but the dimmer doesn't work

Tags: light-fixture, dimmer-switch

I replaced a broken dimmer switch where the dimming happened by positioning the switch in various places to one that has a small lever next to the switch. I turned the power back on and the light fixture works but the dimming does not. Any ideas how I can get that to work? Many thanks. Could it be the type of lightbulbs?

Comment: What type of bulb and what type of dimmer?

Comment: What make and model is the dimmer, and what make and model are the bulbs in question?

Comment: I met with success- realized that they gave different color plates to go over the switch and I had not made sure the switch and dimmer were both at the top when I snapped the cover on. Thank you though.

Comment: @AnnC. please write that up as an _answer_ and, as soon as the system will allow it, click the check-mark next to it. This is a perfectly good answer, not a comment, and, since this is a Question & Answer forum, not a general discussion board, having an official answer helps make the system work.

Answer (score 1):

There are different colored plates to go over the light switch. If the switch, dimmer knob etc. are all not on an up position, the dimmer won't be able to toggle up and down.